# It takes very long time to read '.txt file' how can i solve this problem? ( C )

Tags: c, file-io

there is very long "dict.txt" file.
the size of this file is about 2400273(calculated by fseek, SEEK_END)
this file has lots of char like this 'apple = 사과'(simillar to dictionary)

Main problem is that reading file takes very long time
I couldn't find any solution to solve this problem in GOOGLE
The reason i guessed is associated with using `fgets()` but i don't know exactly.
please help me

here is my code written by C

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int line = 0;
    char txt_str[50];
    FILE* pFile;

    pFile = fopen("dict_test.txt", "r");

    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("file doesn't exist or there is problem to open your file\n");
    }
    else {
        
        do{
            fgets(txt_str, 50, pFile);;
            line++;
        } while (txt_str != EOF);
    }

    printf("%d", line);
    
}
```

**Output**

> couldn't see result because program was continuosly running

**Expected**

> the number of lines of this txt file

Comment: `txt_str` a char array will never be `EOF` an `int` you have to check how many bytes you read instead.

Comment: @cafce25 "you have to check how many bytes you read instead." --> No.  When `fgets()` returns `NULL`, there is nothing about `txt_str[]` that indicated the number of bytes read.  Simple the _return value_ of `fgets()` needs to be tested against `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

**Major**

- OP's code fail to test the return value of `fgets()`.  Code needs to check the return value of `fgets()` to know when to stop. [@A4L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74740390/2410359)

```
        do{
            fgets(txt_str, 50, pFile);;  // fgets() return value not used.
```

**Other**

- Line count should not get incremented when `fgets()` returns `NULL`.
- Line count should not get incremented when `fgets()` read a partial line.  (I. e.) the line was 50 or longer.  Reasonable to use a wider than 50 buffer.
- Line count may exceed `INT_MAX`.  There is always some upper bound, yet trivial to use a wider type.
- Good practice to *close* the stream.
- Another approach to count lines would use `fread()` to read chunks of memory and then look for start of lines.  (Not shown)
- Recommend to print a `'\n'` after the line count.

```
    int main(void) {
      FILE* pFile = fopen("dict_test.txt", "r");
      if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("File doesn't exist or there is problem to open your file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

      unsigned long long line = 0;
      char txt_str[4096];
   
      while (fgets(txt_str, sizeof txt_str, pFile)) {
        if (strlen(txt_str) == sizeof txt_str - 1) { // Buffer full?
          if (txt_str[sizeof txt_str - 1] != '\n') { // Last not \n?
            continue;
          }
        }
        line++;
      }

      fclose(pFile);
      printf("%llu\n", line);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) returns `NULL` on `EOF`.

You are never assigning the result of

```
fgets(txt_str, 50, pFile);
```

to `txt_str`, your program never sees the end of the file and thus enters an endless loop.

try something like this:

```
char* p_str;

 do{
     p_str = fgets(txt_str, 50, pFile);
 } while (p_str != NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I'm sorry that I didn't explain about my problem well .
the problem is speed of reading file.
Too much data, reading the file takes too long.
I think it's because the text is read line by line. Is there a way to read long text quickly?

Comment: @kangking Please read the answer again. Your code, as written, will run *for ever* since it doesn't properly check for when the file has finished. The expression `txt_str != EOF` will *never* be false, so the loop will never end. On a modern computer using any reasonable disk, reading 2.4 MB of data should hardly be noticable, even if done way worse than 50 bytes at a time.

Comment: No, it's not the speed, your program will never finish reading, it enters an [endless loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop) because you never check for the result of `fgets` . The condition in your `while` statement is never met.

Comment: OMG I was stupid. It took a long time, so I didn't check it to the end, but unlike other words that were printed normally, I found that the last word was repeating infinitely. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, that's correct too, OP asked regarding the program never ending the read operation, line count would be then his next problem ;-)